# Rails 4.2 Can't send outgoing mail using mandrill

Tags: heroku, smtp, mandrill, ruby-on-rails-4.2, http-status-code-302

hi iam currently working on an smtp, my problem is that it wont even send an out going email, i was using devise and it has sent an email perfectly but when it comes to another outgoing one it was giving me an error like so when i do some heroku logs

```
An SMTP From address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_from, return_path, sender, or from address.
```

i have already set up the smtp properly and i dont know why this is showing , also when i try locally with my local server its working fine and using a gem letter_opener to see if its working properly and its fine, but when i try with my server it gives me an error.

also have setup the basics

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "mines.com/" }
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
  :port           => "587",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => Rails.application.secrets.mandrill_username,
  :password       => Rails.application.secrets.mandrill_password,
  :domain         => "rigpirate.com",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
```

can somebody help me with this this one as i don't have a clue where to start

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with mandrill. To actually send mail, you need an SMTP "From" address. You local testing is not failing because you are probably not actually delivering mail.

Your code snippet in the question does not show how you are setting the from address.

The from address can be set in three places:

- in `config.action_mailer.default_options`
- as a mailer class `default`
- as a `mail` parameter

i.e.

```
# in app config:
config.action_mailer.default_options = { from: "no-reply@example.org" }   

# in a mailer class:
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'no-reply2@example.org'

  def welcome
    mail(from: 'no-reply3@example.org', to: 'a@b.c')
  end
end
```

See the [ActionMailer docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) for more info.